# Select last 5 words of a paragraph in Regex

Tags: notepad++, regex, adobe-indesign

I want to match last 5 words of every paragraph in a document. I am using Notepad++ and also Adobe InDesign GREP

**Sample Data**

> Here you can find activities to practise your reading skills. Reading will help you to improve your understanding of the language and build your vocabulary.

> The self-study lessons in this section are written and organised by English level based on the Common European Framework of Reference for languages (CEFR). There are different types of texts and interactive exercises that practise the reading skills you need to do well in your studies, to get ahead at work and to communicate in English in your free time.

> Take our free online English test to find out which level to choose. Select your level, from A1 English level (elementary) to C1 English level (advanced), and improve your reading skills at your own speed, whenever it’s convenient for you.

I have written this code which is selecting last word only. Even if I change 5 to 3, it still selects the last word only.

```
(\H*){5}(?=$)
```

Comment: This is not a regex writing service.

Comment: What work have you done so far?

Comment: I have written this code:
`(\H*){5}(?=$)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let's explain your regex:

- `(\H*){5}` matches 5 time 0 or more  non-horizontal spaces, it matches a single word that is, at least, 0 or 5 or more character long.
- `(?=$)` doesn't make sense, you want to use `$`, that is enough.

---

The regex you should use is: `(?:\h\H+){5}$`

- `(?:\h\H+){5}` # 1 horizontal space followed by 1 or more non horizontal spaces, must appears 5 times
- `$`                   # end of line

If you don't want to match the space before  the first word, use:

```
(?:\H+\h){4}\H+$
```

Comment: Thanks for dowvote, may I know why?

Comment: Thank you. This code worked. `(?:\h\H+){5}$` 

This was also very helpful `(?:\H+\h){4}\H+$` 

Is there a way to skip the full stop at the end ?

Comment: @Shahid: Just replace `\H` with `\S`: `(?:\h\S+){5}$` or `(?:\S+\h){4}\S+$`